# Need help with のが and のある in this sentence

Tags: grammar, syntax, cleft-sentences

> で、そのときに私がいつも思い出す**のが**、映画『シンドラーのリスト』**のある**場面です。ご覧になった方いますか？シンドラーのリスト。
>   <sub>(Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xs-XWk_oQA at 0:47)</sub>

Can anyone shed some light on the uses of のが and のある in this sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

そのときに私がいつも思い出す*のが* = **What** comes up to my mind whenever in the situation like this,

のある = "の” + "ある" = **a** scene **of** a movie "Schindler's list".